# Disable jQueryMobile yes/no slider animation

Tags: jquery, mobile

My Yes/No Slider Code looks like the following.

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain" class="select">
    <label for="reset">Can animation be turned off???</label>
    <select name="reset" data-role="slider">
       <option value="false" selected="selected">No</option>
       <option value="true">Yes</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

The animations of switching from yes to no or viceversa seems very choppy in my test devices.
How can I turn this off globally? I already have

```
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
$.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
```

Can't seem to find a way to disable the Slider animations off...

Comment: Good Question. I'm searching for a solution right away. Did you find any answer on this?

Answer (score 0):

My "solution" was to split my big page into several pages in multipage style [how described here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/multipage-template.html).

It seems that it has to do with the amount of fields displayed at once, in relation to the power of the underlying machine (on Android-Tablet there was the prob, but with same page on desktop it is gone.

`$.mobile.defaultPageTransition`and `$.mobile.defaultDialogTransition`only affecting the animations of page hide/show and has nothing to do with the animation of input-fields. That is CSS3-Transition.